# Meaning of "las" in "Si descubro que un solo dólar fue a parar a esas prostitutas, se las verás conmigo"

Tags: modismos, pronombres, objetos-directos

I have read the following sentence:

> Si descubro que un solo dólar de contribuyentes estadounidenses fue a parar a esas prostitutas, se las verás conmigo.

I know that "verse con alguien" here means "to deal with somebody"/"to have problems with somebody", but what does "las" refer to in this sentence? "Esas prostitutas"? That does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an idiom.  The object "las" doesn't represent anything specific in the sentence.  It's just part of the expression.

Here are some dictionary entries for **vérselas**:

[Oxford Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/verselas_con):

> tener un enfrentamiento con alguien o algo
>
> *Si no dejas de insultarme, te las verás conmigo.*

[Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=verselas):

> enfrentarse a alguien:  confront, speak with, deal with
>
> *Mi abuelo es un hombre severo: si sigues fastidiándolo, te las verás con él.*

I think a better usage example would be

> Hay que respetar a la mamá.  Si no, te las verás conmigo. *You need to respect your mother.  If you don't, you'll have me to answer to.*